# Working with URI's in mix mode (Windows and Linux)

Tags: java, uri

I am trying to work with URI's, when both client and server are Unix or both are Windows no issue... When working with a mixed mode (one is Windows and the other is server) I'm facing this behavior:

e.g.
I entered this path in my angular client app:

> /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/webapps/...

and it was saved as URI in db with this format:

> file:///**C:**/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/webapps/...

My server is deployed on windows **(from eclipse-> run as server -> tomcat)**
so it seems that because it's running on windows it's adding the C:\ and switching the forward slashes with backward slashes!

```
Paths.get(path).toUri().toString();
```

or

```
Paths.get(new URI(((FileResourceId) resource).Uri.toString())).toString();
```

In the other way to get the path from URI I'm using:

```
Paths.get(((FileResourceId) resource).Uri).toFile().getPath();
```

getting this value back:

> C:\opt\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\webapps...

I guess that when Linux path will be accessible by a shared system it won't behave that way!
How can I be system independent?

Thanks.

Comment: URIs **always** use forward slashes, on all platforms.  It’s in the specification.

Comment: Yes,  That's not my problem. Please note that c: was added to linux path when running the code on windows server

Comment: Are you saying you want a `file:` URI created on one machine to be usable on another machine?

Comment: In case of shared file system it can be. But let's say that we don't have access from one machine to other... so how can I get the path from URI in such case? I mean without manipulating the URI text itself.

Comment: I don’t know of any way to refer to a shared file system, that uses a consistent file path structure on both Windows and Linux.  This is one of the reasons HTTP was invented.  Since Tomcat is involved anyway, perhaps you should make your file available via HTTP or HTTPS.  That will allow a consistent means of accessing it, assuming the web application always uses a consistent context root.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds logical.
I just wanted to confirm that there is no such a way.